# Check if a string ends with a decimal in Python 2

Tags: python, list, ends-with

I want to check if a string ends with a decimal of varying numbers, from searching for a while, the closest solution I found was to input values into a tuple and using that as the condition for endswith(). But is there any shorter way instead of inputting every possible combination?

I tried hard coding the end condition but if there are new elements in the list it wont work for those, I also tried using regex it returns other elements together with the decimal elements as well. Any help would be appreciated

```
list1 = ["abcd 1.01", "zyx 22.98", "efgh 3.0", "qwe -70"]

for e in list1:
    if e.endswith('.0') or e.endswith('.98'):
        print 'pass'
```

Edit: Sorry should have specified that I do not want to have 'qwe -70' to be accepted, only those elements with a decimal point should be accepted

Comment: so what's the definition of decimal? Why isn't 1.01 a decimal.

Comment: It looks like numbers in each is string is split by a space so why don't you just do `float(e.split()[-1])` and return false when it raises a `ValueError`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to propose another solution: using [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) to search for an ending decimal.

You can define a regular expression for an ending decimal with the following regex `[-+]?[0-9]*\.[0-9]+$`.

The regex broken apart:

- `[-+]?`: optional - or + symbol at the beginning
- `[0-9]*`: zero or more digits
- `\.`: required dot
- `[0-9]+`: one or more digits
- `$`: must be at the end of the line

Then we can test the regular expression to see if it matches any of the members in the list:

```
import re

regex = re.compile('[-+]?[0-9]*\.[0-9]+$')
list1 = ["abcd 1.01", "zyx 22.98", "efgh 3.0", "qwe -70", "test"]

for e in list1:
  if regex.search(e) is not None:
    print e + " passes"
  else:
    print e  + " does not pass"
```

The output for the previous script is the following:

```
abcd 1.01 passes
zyx 22.98 passes
efgh 3.0 passes
qwe -70 does not pass
test does not pass
```

Comment: works perfectly, only accepts the elements with a decimal point. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your example data leaves many possibilities open:

Last character is a digit:

```
e[-1].isdigit()
```

Everything after the last space is a number:

```
try:
    float(e.rsplit(None, 1)[-1])
except ValueError:
    # no number
    pass
else:
    print "number"
```

Using regular expressions:

```
re.match('[.0-9]$', e)
```

Comment: this will accept 'qwe -70' which I do not want, only the other 3 should be accepted

Answer (score 0):

```
suspects = [x.split() for x in list1] # split by the space in between and get the second item as in your strings

# iterate over to try and cast it to float -- if not it will raise ValueError exception

for x in suspects:
    try:
        float(x[1])
        print "{} - ends with float".format(str(" ".join(x)))
    except ValueError:
        print "{} - does not ends with float".format(str(" ".join(x)))

## -- End pasted text --

abcd 1.01 - ends with float
zyx 22.98 - ends with float
efgh 3.0 - ends with float
qwe -70 - ends with float
```

Comment: this returns 'qwe -70' but I only want to have those elements in the list that has a decimal point like the other 3

Comment: If you want to check if a number is whole number or not, you can use the is_integer method for floats. To check for the decimal point you may need to regex or split again and check.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#float.is_integer

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for this case:

```
regex = r"([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)"

list1 = ["abcd 1.01", "zyx 22.98", "efgh 3.0", "qwe -70"]

for e in list1:
    str = e.split(' ')[1]
    if re.search(regex, str):
       print True #Code for yes condition
    else:
       print False #Code for no condition
```

Answer (score 0):

As you correctly guessed, `endswith()` is not a good way to look at the solution, given that the number of combinations is basically infinite. The way to go is - as many suggested - a regular expression that would match the end of the string to be a decimal point followed by any count of digits. Besides that, keep the code simple, and readable. The `strip()` is in there just in case one the input string has an extra space at the end, which would unnecessarily complicate the regex.
You can see this in action at: https://eval.in/649155

```
import re
regex = r"[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$"

list1 = ["abcd 1.01", "zyx 22.98", "efgh 3.0", "qwe -70"]

for e in list1:
    if re.search(regex, e.strip()):
       print e, 'pass'
```

Answer (score 0):

The flowing maybe help:

```
import re

reg = re.compile(r'^[a-z]+ \-?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$')

if re.match(reg, the_string):
    do something...
else:
    do other...
```